# Pass Multiple Parameters into an Array List (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to set up an array list that will store items on a grocery list. I would like the for the list to store the name, price, and tax information for each item. Is it possible to set up an ArrayList so that it accepts both String and integer parameters? I've included my code below:

```
public class ItemList
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private ArrayList<String> items;
private String itemName;
private int cost;
private String taxable;


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class ItemList
 */
public ItemList()
{
   items=new ArrayList<>();
    
}

/**
 * Adds an item to the ItemList
 */
public void addItem(String itemName, int cost, String taxable)
{
    items.add(itemName, cost, taxable);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be to create a `Item` class and have a `List` of these.  The Item would have a constructor that takes the necessary variables.

Then you could do

```
private ArrayList<Item> items;
.....
public void addItem(String itemName, int cost, String taxable)
{
    items.add(new Item(itemName, cost, taxable));
}
```